# smallest element in Partial ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Every finite partial order has a smallest element, where an element x $\epsilon$ S
is said to be the smallest if for all y $\epsilon$ S; it is the case that (x,y)$\epsilon$R.
here R is relation defining partial order.
How could we can prove or disprove this statement

Comment: Begin by defining "finite set".

Comment: @dfeuer:i can't get you, what u wan't to say is this claim correct or false?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It's called a brain fart. I missed that bit.

Comment: @dfeuer: No worries: done it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Disprove it by finding a counterexample; you can make with as few as two elements. Thinking about Hasse diagrams may help you to visualize what you need. (Of course the empty partial order also provides a counterexample, but I suspect that the finite set was intended to be non-empty.

Comment: how can a empty set be counterexample? it would be related to itself due to reflexivity of R and become smallest element.

Comment: @Coding143: What would? When the underlying set is empty, there's nothing there to be related to itself. I didn't say that $\varnothing$ was an **element** of the partial order: I said that the partial order **had** no elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For a finite poset with no smallest element, try something like the set $\{1,2,3,4, a, b, c\}$, where you order the numbers in the natural way, and the letters in the natural way, and make no specification about "mixed" couples.

There is no such thing as **the** smallest element.

You can easily cut this example down to a smaller size if you like.